# Fill in a form OK, but validation does not take the fields content

Tags: javascript, java, android, forms, fill

On the following page :
     https://teleservices.ac-nancy-metz.fr/login/ct_logon_vk.jsp

And with the following lines, the login field and password field are filled in, but when I validate, manually or programmtically, the fields seemed not to be filled in

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.travail_activity_webview);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String urlNewString) {
            if (!loadingFinished) {
                redirect = true;
            }
            loadingFinished = false;
            view.loadUrl(urlNewString);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            loadingFinished = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.e("Page finished", "url : " +url);
            if(!redirect){
                loadingFinished = true;
            }

            if(loadingFinished && !redirect){
                if (!connected) {
                    completionIdentifiants();
                    connected=true;
                } else if (!portailled){
                    accesPortail();
                    portailled=true;
                }


            } else{
                redirect = false;
            }
        }
    });

private void accesPortail() {
    webView.loadUrl("https://teleservices.ac-nancy-metz.fr/login/ct_logon_vk.jsp");
}



public void completionIdentifiants() {
    webView.loadUrl("javascript:var x = document.getElementById('user').value = 'mylogin';");
    webView.loadUrl("javascript:var y = document.getElementById('password').value = 'mypass';");
    webView.loadUrl("javascript:var z = window.document.getElementById('myform').submit();");
    webView.loadUrl("javascript:alert('Test')");
}
```

The field are visually filled in, but the value is not taken after submitting.
Their content is just erased...

I tried a lot of combinations, without success.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is about your **shouldOverrideUrlLoading** method, please take a look at this Android documenation: [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient) and search for shouldOverrideUrlLoading section, you need to **return false** in this method.

Comment: After submitting the request by this line, I checked out the request of my browser, the request had sent password:"mypass" and user:"mylogin" as params. Your JS side seems to be alright.

Comment: Maybe is it because of my webview ? Because even if I put a false login, I do not get an error message, whereas if I do that in a classic browser, I get one.

Comment: When I directly put the 3 lines in the Chrome browser of my computer, everything works as expected : access granted, and a new page is loading.

Comment: Would you provide the pieces of code relating to your webview ? And does this line work? : webView.loadUrl("javascript:alert('Test')");

Comment: Indeed, your "alert" does nothing ! Strange, because the fields are filled in with the other javascript call...
I've edited my code and added the missing lines.

Comment: Maybe that's because you have inserted the "alert" line after the "submit", BTW, on what SDK version are you testing ?
About your **shouldOverrideUrlLoading** method, please take a look at this Android documenation: [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient) and search for **shouldOverrideUrlLoading**, it seems you need to return false in this method. let me know if it helped

Comment: Got it, thanks to the "false" return. Thank you so much, you saved my day !